# How to connect a .xml file to Java Project?

Tags: java, xml

I need to connect .xml file to my Java Project to work properly, but I have no idea how to acomplish it, any ideas, please?

Comment: Just a guess, is the name of your .xml file accendantly `pom.xml`?

Comment: The name of my .xml file is war.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("your .xml path")` load .xml file